# Descending order for proc surveylogistic

Tags: sas

I'm trying to do change from *PROC logistic* to a *PROC surveylogistic* but there is no descending option for the surveylogistic. Is there any trick to do it?

Here is my *PROC logistic*:

```
proc logistic data = myData desc;
    model depVar = indepvar /expb  CLPARM=WALD;
    *weight weightVar;
    format depVar depVarF.;
run; quit;
```

And my *PROC surveylogistic* :

```
proc surveylogistic data=myData order=internal ;
    *strata var1 var2 var3 /list;
    class depVar;
    model depVar = indepVar  /expb CLPARM ;
    format depVar depVarF.;
    *weight weightVar;
run; quit;
```

Any ideas will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer after doing a little more research. I just need to add /desc for the class.

```
proc surveylogistic data=myData order=internal ;
    *strata var1 var2 var3 /list;
    class depVar /desc;
    model depVar = indepVar  /expb CLPARM ;
    format depVar depVarF.;
    *weight weightVar;
run; quit;
```